# Delphi Intraweb bundled SSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, intraweb

I am using intraweb XIV bundled edition for Delphi XE7. When i tested one intraweb XII application in this new bundled version the SSL/TLS  is not working. the bundled version wont support SSL/TLS?

Comment: For HTTP communication, it should be possible to supply SSL/TLS through a reverse proxy such as nginx or Apache HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this feature matrix](http://www.atozedsoftware.com/IntraWeb/FeatureMatrixXII.EN.aspx) the SSL support seems only available in the ultimate edition of Intraweb .